# Get the proper FQL source_id when querying multiple source_id's

Tags: facebook, stream, facebook-fql

Given the following Facebook Query Language:

`SELECT source_id FROM stream WHERE source_id in ('301470456547727', '194053380668945')`

I expected to receive two different `source_id`'s for the objects, however every `source_id` is the last number I pass in. See this in action here:

[Facebook API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20source_id%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20in%20%28%27301470456547727%27%2C%20%27194053380668945%27%29)

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Edit: I also tried `target_id` with the same results.

Edit 2: Also I'm not sure if I should post this as a separate question, if you also select the 'message' column it seems for some of the posts the message value is entirely empty, even though there is data when accessed via the browser, is it me or facebook?

Comment: I'm sorry that link appears to be breaking, I tried to make it a named link but that was broken too, copy/paste works until someone can help me fix it.

Comment: Formatted and linkified for you :)

Comment: @DMCS Thanks, I see you had the same problem I did, when you visit the link to explorer the query is broken. :-)

Comment: Thanks, when I tried it just seemed to break after fql=q, but I think we fixed it at the same time ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize if this answer isn't particularly helpful to you...but Facebook is exceptionally quirky at times.

I'm not sure why you're interested in those values specifically, but if you can retrieve those values using another FQL query, that may work out better for you.  No guarantees without more context though.

ps, about the empty messages column, some story types don't store their text in the messages/text column where you would expect.  A general rule of thumb is: if the user didn't write it, its not going to be in the messages column.  There are exceptions to every rule, so don't quote me on that.

Comment: ,Regarding the messages column, I see that you are correct, unfortunately there seems to be a lot of places it could be stored :-)
If there isn't a more thorough answer in the next few days I'll accept this because, as you say, it should be fairly easy to query this when needed.

Comment: See post [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fnbuyandsell/10151332257020293/). See what she says about XBox 360? Now see this [graph api query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20%20post_id%2Cviewer_id%2Capp_id%2Csource_id%2Cupdated_time%2Ccreated_time%2Cfilter_key%2Cattribution%2Cactor_id%2Ctarget_id%2Cmessage%2Capp_data%2Caction_links%2Cattachment%2Cimpressions%2Ccomments%2Clikes%2Cprivacy%2Cpermalink%2Cxid%2Ctagged_ids%2Cmessage_tags%2Cdescription%2Cdescription_tags%2Ctype%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20post_id%3D'37145675292_10151332257020293')

Comment: P.S. That's all the columns I could find at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

Comment: you might want to post this as a separate question.